# Looping GPIO pins on a raspberry pi 4 model B

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm currently trying to set up a loop for a project I'm working on, but i cant seem to get it to work the way that i want it to. pins 2 and 4 are set to high when the script isn't running, and when it does run pins 3 and 4 don't alternate, and pin 2 remains high. Is there a better way to code the general gist of the setup or is there a simple fix that I haven't seen being the problem?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
# fill
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
# blend
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
# empty

a = 13  # time for initial fill
c = 60  # time for initial blend
e = 25  # time for intital empty
b = c + e + 15  # time for pause intital fill
d = a + e + 15  # time for pause intital blend
f = a + c + 15  # time for pause intital empty
aa = 13  # time for continous fill
cc = 60  # time for continous blend
ee = 25  # time for continous empty
bb = cc + ee + 15  # time for pause continous fill
dd = aa + ee + 15  # time for pause continous blend
ff = aa + cc + 15  # time for pause continous empty

gpio_2 = "GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)"
gpio_3 = "GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)"
gpio_4 = "GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)"

for i in range(1):  # Inital flow

    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(a)
    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(b)
    GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(d)
    GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(c)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(f)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(e)

if gpio_2 == 1:
    print('filling')
else:
    print('filling paused')
if gpio_3 == 1:
    print('blending')
else:
    print('blending paused')
if gpio_4 == 1:
    print('emptying')
else:
    print('emptying paused')


for i in range(1, 9):  # continous flow

    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(aa)
    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(bb)
    GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(dd)
    GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(cc)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(ff)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(ee)

for i in range(1, 1):  # final pass through

    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(600)
    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(600)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what behavior you're trying to achieve?